# how can I create ui the same as picture

Tags: android, cardview

I am developing android app and how can I create ui like below picture

and below my xml I have played around but it is not giving expected output any suggestion will be greatly appreciated and hints welcome I dont know where exactly I am making mistake

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/articleSource"
            android:paddingBottom="45dp"
            android:text="22222222"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bbc_sport"
        android:layout_height="60dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/articleSource"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="90dp"
        android:text="News blalalalal"/>




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/articleTime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="90dp"
        android:text="News blalalalal"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        >

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Do you want to know how to just build the row item layout in the list or the entire layout?

Comment: You are not using anything correctly in that constraint layout. It will work fine when you will go through these links thoroughly and apply them.

Check these official documentation links:

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout


https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

Answer (score 0):

If you mean item list you maybe can do this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="bbc"
            tools:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="1\n2\n3\n" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageCategory"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/articleTitle"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
            tools:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/articleTitle"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageCategory"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:text="Onefootbal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/articleTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/articleCategory"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:text="- 1h"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to build the whole screen I'd suggest you using Epoxy library by Airbnb https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy

You will basically treat this screen as `RecyclerView` which has 2 types of layouts - item without image (as the one on top) and item with image (all the bottom ones).

It will take some time to learn the library but it will be very handy especially if your layout is reusable and other screens use similar items